# Bluez install with raspberrypi

Tags: raspberry-pi, bluez

I tried to install bleuz 5.44 but get this error during make process

[error see here](https://pastebin.com/HRd1EMPi)

```
Makefile:5611: recipe for target 'gdbus/mainloop.lo' failed
make[1]: *** [gdbus/mainloop.lo] Error 1
Makefile:3121: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I followed the instruction here https://github.com/getsenic/nuimo-linux-python#installing-bluez-from-sources

Comment: Can you expand your formatted block to include more of that pasteboard error? If readers need to refer to a Pastie to understand the question, then it is probably off-topic. If you can't fit all of the error log into the question, then fit as much as you can.